# Oracle: how to write a query with enable / disable WHERE condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I've thougth this way to implement a parametrizable query.
Do you know any variant?

```
WITH temp AS (SELECT 'case1' case FROM DUAL)
SELECT 1
  FROM temp
 WHERE    (    (1 = DECODE (case, 'case1', 1, 0))
           AND SYSDATE > TO_DATE ('01/01/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
       OR (    (1 = DECODE (case, 'case2', 1, 0))
           AND SYSDATE < TO_DATE ('01/01/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
```

Comment: It would be better if you told us what you were really trying to achieve, this looks 'strange' at present

Comment: A parametric query with relaxable condition. I want to create an unique view with the possibility to enable / disable a condition of where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use case

```
WITH temp AS (SELECT 'case1' _case FROM DUAL)
SELECT 1
  FROM temp
 WHERE   
 1 = case
      when _case = 'case1'
      AND SYSDATE > TO_DATE ('01/01/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
      then 1
      when _case = 'case2'
      AND SYSDATE > TO_DATE ('01/01/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
      then 1
      else 0
     end 
;
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems awkward.  You can do this with just basic logic:

```
WITH temp AS (SELECT 'case1' case FROM DUAL)
SELECT 1
FROM temp
WHERE ((case = 'case1') and SYSDATE > TO_DATE('01/01/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY')) or
      ((case = 'case2') and SYSDATE < TO_DATE('01/01/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a function:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION x ( p_case IN VARCHAR2, p_date IN VARCHAR2 )
 RETURN INTEGER
 IS
 BEGIN
      IF p_case = 'case1' AND TO_DATE(p_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') < SYSDATE THEN RETURN 1;
      ELSE IF p_case = 'case2' AND TO_DATE(p_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') < SYSDATE THEN RETURN 1;
      ELSE RETURN 0;
      END IF;
 END;

 SELECT 1 FROM dual WHERE x('case1', '01/01/2013') = 1;
```